# Prefix Decrement vs Subtract

Tags: c#, math, tween

```
public static float ExpoInOut(float from, float to, float time)
{
    if ((time /= .5f) < 1f)
        return Mathf.Lerp(from, to, .5f * Mathf.Pow(2f, 10f * (time - 1f)));
    return Mathf.Lerp(from, to, .5f * (-Mathf.Pow(2f, -10f * --time) + 2f));
}
```

The first step in both cases is to subtract 1 from time.

The second one saves that value back into time, but since it is not used again does not matter?
The first could use **--time** or the second could use **(time - 1f)** and the result is the same?

The first way might even be better if not saving.

Thanks.

edit: source: http://robertpenner.com/easing/

Comment: Yes, they will give the same result. Use the one that seems more comfortable to you and will be more readable in the future. (which I would argue is probably `time - 1`)

Comment: Would be worth inspecting the IL - you may well find that the compiler generates the same code for each, and even if not, the jitter might deal with it.

Comment: Personally, I dislike side-effects inside expressions. With a quick read of the code, you may miss that the value of time is changed in the if statement. So I would have avoided both side-effects & used something like _"time /= 0.5f; time--; if (time < 0f) return Mathf.Lerp(from, to, .5f * Mathf.Pow(2f, 10f * time)); return Mathf.Lerp(from, to, .5f * (-Mathf.Pow(2f, -10f * time) + 2f));"_

Comment: this seems kind of like a penner code 'watermark' idk why use both in same function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good use on `--time` instead of `time--`. You're right that `--time` vs `time - 1f` doesn't really matter (from a code perspective) if you're not saving the new value of `time` but from a readability perspective you should go with the more verbose one. That being said you should always strive for readability (especially if the performance impact is 0 or negligible). You may find it more readable/supportable to do something like

```
public static float ExpoInOut(float from, float to, float time)
{
    time /= 0.5f;
    time--; 
    if (time < 0f) 
        return Mathf.Lerp(from, to, .5f * Mathf.Pow(2f, 10f * time)); 
    return Mathf.Lerp(from, to, .5f * (-Mathf.Pow(2f, -10f * time) + 2f));
}
```

My general rule of thumb is if you're doing math/functions inside of the parameter passing section of another method, you should minimize it as best as possible, even if that means breaking it out into smaller private methods.

Comment: I think you have proved my point about side-effects in expressions. _time_ needs dividing by 0.5 before the 1 is subtracted!!

Comment: @PualF you're a 100% right. Let me fix that up, that'd be a bad example wouldn't it?

Comment: You also changed the bracketing for the second Mathf.Pow.

Comment: @PaulF, think I've got it sorted. Added a second example that would probably help prevent exactly what happened when I did the first example. Too much going on in too little of a space.

Comment: That seems far more complex than the code I put into my comment - if you corrected your first example I think it would be better than your second example. An improvement maybe to change the if statement to an if/else statement to calculate the third parameter & just have a single return statement (I know some people only like a single return from a function)

Comment: @PaulF, you're entirely too right. I feel wrong using yours as mine, so if you post an answer with yours I'll delete answer.

Comment: As this is a very opinion based question of coding style then I am content to leave my code as a comment & let you take the credit.